# Date Format changing automatically in pandas data frame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Here I am taking data from .xlsx file and populating pandas data-frame. In the file, one date column has this type of entry "30-11-2016". After reading data from the excel the date entry is getting converted to some other format("2016-11-30 00:00:00").

```
df2 = read_excel('path.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1')
print(df2.head())
```

What should I do to treat dates in xlsx file as a string in pandas?

Comment: In my case that xlsx file can have different formats(03-03-16, 03/03/16, 3 Apr 2016 ) of date. I just need the date as a string in my data-frame irrelevant of its date format

Comment: Priorly I don't know the date format how the date can be. So converting to specific format later doesn't work.